# Python error with order of property function

Tags: python, methods, properties, arguments

For some reason when I switch around the arguments of the property function it throws an error. I just want to understand why.

```py
class Geeks:
    def __init__(self):
        self._age = 0

    # function to get value of _age
    def get_age(self):
        print("getter method called")
        return self._age

    # function to set value of _age
    def set_age(self, a):
        print("setter method called")
        self._age = a

    age = property(get_age, set_age)

mark = Geeks()
mark.age = 10
print(mark.age)
```

This outputs:

```
setter method called
getter method called
10
```

The error occurs when I switch around `age = property(get_age, set_age)`  like so

```py
class Geeks:
    def __init__(self):
        self._age = 0

    # function to get value of _age
    def get_age(self):
        print("getter method called")
        return self._age

    # function to set value of _age
    def set_age(self, a):
        print("setter method called")
        self._age = a

    age = property(set_age, get_age)

mark = Geeks()
mark.age = 10
print(mark.age)
```

This outputs

```
ERROR!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 18, in <module>
TypeError: Geeks.get_age() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Why am I not allowed to switch around the arguments?

Comment: Please review and correct your code format

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The reason is the first parameter is the ```getter``` and the second parameter is the ```setter```.  ```get_age()``` returns a value.  But once you switch that as a ```setter```,  it expects a second parameter.  But ```get_age()``` doesn't have or need one.

Comment: You might find it easier to use the @property decorator. Or you could just read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/functions.html#property) for the *property()* function

Comment: When I run your code I get an `IndentationError`.

Answer (score 1):

In the problematic `property` call, you have the setter and getter in the wrong order. In the absence of *named* parameters, Python will insist you follow the order required (positional).

If you're using *positional* parameters (and you are), then the getter should be first. Because you've swapped them, the argument count will be wrong for both, because Python will *call* them based on the facts that:

- a getter is a function that takes *no* arguments (other than `self`) and returns a value; and
- a setter is defined as a function that takes *one* argument (again, other than `self`) and returns nothing.

If you really want them in the order you have, you need to *name* them explicitly so that Python will adapt to your order:

```py
age = property(fset=set_age, fget=get_age)
```

---

However, one thing you *may* want to consider is the use of the property decorator to make it clearer which function is for which purpose. For your case, that would entail something like:

```py
class Geeks:
    def __init__(self):
        self._age = 0

    @property
    def age(self):
        print("getter method called")
        return self._age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, new_age):
        print("setter method called")
        self._age = new_age

mark = Geeks()
mark.age = 10
print(mark.age)
```